# Compute the least distance from the point $P$ to the line $l_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $l_1$ be the line of intersection between the planes $M_1 : x + 4y − 5z = −3$ and $M_2 : 2x − y − z = 3$.

Compute the least distance from the point $P = (−2, 10, 4)$  to $l_1$. (ON-system assumed.)

I assume the first step would be to find a parametric representation of the line $l_1$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why is $l_2$ given?

Comment: @cosmo5 Ops sorry, there's another question b), so $l_2$ isn't relevant for the question I posted.

Comment: No problem. Here is a hint. Note that $l_1$ will be perpendicular to normals of both the planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a normal vector to $M_1$ is $\vec n_1 =\begin{bmatrix}1 & 4 & -5 \end{bmatrix}^\top,$ while for $M_2$ we get $\vec n_2 = \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}^\top.$

The line of intersection will be in the direction of the cross product $\vec n_1 \times \vec n_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-9 & -9 & -9 \end{bmatrix}^\top.$ Equivalently, we can make it easier choosing $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^\top.$

A line in this direction will necessarily cross the $xy$ plane, and hence we can look at $z=0, $ going back to the equations of the planes:

\begin{align}
M_1 &: x + 4y − 5z = −3\\
M_2 &: 2x − y − z = 3
\end{align}

$x+4y=-3\implies x= -4y -3,$ and $2(-4y -3)-y=3\implies y = -1.$ Going back then, $x=-4(-1)-3=1.$

The equation of the line is then

$$l_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\lambda \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

---

The vector orthogonal to the line of intersection $l_1$ that goes through the point $P$ will be $\vec e =\begin{bmatrix}-2 -(1+\lambda) & 10-(-1+\lambda) & 4-(0+\lambda) \end{bmatrix}^\top$

and because of orthogonality to $l_1,$ it will have a zero dot product with $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^\top.$

$$\begin{bmatrix}-3 -\lambda \\ 11-\lambda \\ 4-\lambda \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}= 0$$

Therefore $\lambda=4,$ and the point on $l_1$ is $(5,3,4).$ The vector $\vec e=\begin{bmatrix}-7&7&0\end{bmatrix}^\top.$

The distance is $$\Vert \vec e\Vert = 7\sqrt 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Finding the parametric expression from the cross product of normal vectors of both planes (as suggested by @cosmo5) is generally a good approach, but it seems a little over-kill in this problem, as the following equations are really easy to solve.

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
   x+4y-5z & = -3 \\
   2x-y-z & = 3
\end{aligned}\right.  \rightarrow
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x & = z+1\\
y & = z-1
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Now you can plug in the expression for $x,y$ in terms of $z$ in the distance formula

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{(x+2)^2 + (y-10)^2 + (z-4)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{(z+3)^2 + (z-11)^2 + (z-4)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{3z^2 -24 z +146} \\
&= \sqrt{3(z-4)^2 + 98} \geq 7\sqrt{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

- $\ds{\vec{r}_{0} \equiv \pars{\substack{2 \\[1mm] 0\\[1mm] 1}}}$ and $\ds{\vec{r}_{1} \equiv \pars{\substack{\phantom{-}0 \\[1mm] -2\\[1mm] -1}}}$  are points of the line $\ds{\ell_{1}}$.
- $\ds{\vec{r}\pars{\xi} = \vec{r}_{0} + \xi\,\vec{n}}$  "describes" the line $\ds{\ell_{1}}$ where
  $\ds{\xi \in \mathbb{R}}$ and
  $\ds{\vec{n} = \vec{r}_{1} - \vec{r}_{0} =
  \pars{\substack{-2 \\[1mm] -2\\[1mm] -2}}}$.

The solution is given by minimizing
$$
\on{d}_{2}\pars{\xi} \equiv
\pars{\vec{r}_{0} + \xi\,\vec{n} - \vec{p}}^{2}
\quad\mbox{where}\quad\vec{p} \equiv
\pars{\substack{-2 \\[1mm] 10 \\[1mm] \phantom{-}4}} 
$$

- Then,
  \begin{align}
  \on{d}_{2}\pars{\xi} & =
  n^{2}\xi^{2} +
  2\pars{\vec{r}_{0} - \vec{p}}\cdot\vec{n}\xi + 
  \pars{\vec{r}_{0} - \vec{p}}^{2}
  \\[5mm] & =
  n^{2}\left\{\bracks{\xi +
  {\pars{\vec{r}_{0} - \vec{p}}\cdot\vec{n} \over n^{2}}}^{2}\right.
  \\[2mm] &\ \left.\phantom{n^{2}\left\{\left[\right.\right.}-
  {\bracks{\pars{\vec{r}_{0}- \vec{p}}\cdot\vec{n}}^{2}
  \over n^{4}} +
  {\pars{\vec{r}_{0} - \vec{p}}^{2} \over n^{2}}\right\}
  \\[5mm] & \geq
  \color{red}{\pars{\vec{r}_{0} - \vec{p}}^{2} -
  {\bracks{\pars{\vec{r}_{0}- \vec{p}}\cdot\vec{n}}^{2}
  \over n^{2}}}
  \\[5mm] & =
  \pars{\vec{r}_{0} - \vec{p}}^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\phi}
  \\[2mm] & \phi \equiv
  \angle\pars{\vec{r}_{0} - \vec{p},\vec{n}}
  \end{align}
  The $\ds{\color{red}{red}}$ term squared root is the solution. Plug in the known values.
  $$
  Answer = \bbx{7\root{2} \approx 9.8995} \\
  $$